# How to initial check elements in a CheckboxTreeviewer

Tags: java, checkbox, treeview, swt, jface

I'm using a custom Dialog with a CheckboxTreeViewer inside my GMF Editor, which works fine so far, as you can see below:

[image: CheckboxTreeviewer]

After closing the Dialog, the selected element are saved so far. Now my Problem:

When I open the dialog again, all elements are unchecked. So I thought it would be easy to tell the treeViewer that specific elements should be initially checked.

But it turned out that it's not that easy, as the Tree initially consist of the root element. The other elements are not added until the tree expands. Elements are added by calling the *getChildren(Object parentElement)* of the ContentProvider.

So it seems that I can't check specific elements initially, but rather have to provide a dynamically approach. I'm looking for something like an element added listener, but there seems none to exist.

Here is the part, where I'm creating the CheckboxTreeViewer

```
Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
        tv = new CheckboxTreeViewer(container, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL
                | SWT.V_SCROLL);
        tv.getTree().setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH));
        tv.setAutoExpandLevel(2);
        tv.setContentProvider(new FeaturePropertyDialogContentProvider(this));
        tv.setLabelProvider(new FeaturePropertyDialogLabelProvider());
        tv.setInput(productLine);
        tv.setExpandPreCheckFilters(true);
        return container;
```

And here is the getChildren method of my ContentProvider:

```
@Override
    public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
        if (parentElement instanceof PL) {
            PL p = (PL) parentElement;
            return new Object[] { p.getPropertyList() };
        }
        else if (parentElement instanceof PropertyList) {
            PropertyList propertyList = (PropertyList) parentElement;
            return propertyList.getGeneralPlatforms().toArray();
        } else if (parentElement instanceof GeneralPlatform) {
            GeneralPlatform platform = (GeneralPlatform) parentElement;
            return platform.getHardwareElements().toArray();
        } 
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on this?

--------------------Solution---------------------

Found the following solution by myself, which works fine for me so far:

```
tv.expandAll();
tv.setCheckedElements(preSelectedProperties.toArray());
tv.collapseAll();
tv.expandToLevel(2);
```

Comment: A workaround: expand tree -> select items -> collapse tree back. All done programatically.

Comment: But how? When the user opens the tree, I don't know where to hook in. It has to happen when the tree is build up the first time. After that, the user can coose what to select/deselect. I attached some code above to make it more clear. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

You should add a listener on the tree viewer to get a notification when a node gets expanded (method addTreeListener() on TreeViewer). At that time, the nodes are already in the tree, and you can check the check-box.

Here is a snippet of a tree that sets the check state when the tree is expanded:

```
public class Snippet {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Map<String, Boolean> userChecks = new HashMap<>();

    final CheckboxTreeViewer tv = new CheckboxTreeViewer(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    GridData gridData = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
    tv.getTree().setLayoutData(gridData);
    final FeaturePropertyDialogContentProvider provider = new FeaturePropertyDialogContentProvider(tv);
    tv.setContentProvider(provider);
    tv.setInput("root");
    tv.addCheckStateListener(new ICheckStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void checkStateChanged(CheckStateChangedEvent event) {
            userChecks.put((String) event.getElement(), event.getChecked());
        }
    });
    tv.addTreeListener(new ITreeViewerListener() {
        @Override
        public void treeCollapsed(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
        }

        @Override
        public void treeExpanded(TreeExpansionEvent event) {
            final Object element = event.getElement();
            final Object[] children = provider.getChildren(element);
            for (Object child : children) {
                if (userChecks.containsKey(child)) {
                    tv.setChecked(child, userChecks.get(child));
                } else if (child.equals("b")) {
                    tv.setChecked(child, true);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    shell.setSize(200, 200);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static class FeaturePropertyDialogContentProvider implements ITreeContentProvider {

    final CheckboxTreeViewer tv;

    private FeaturePropertyDialogContentProvider(CheckboxTreeViewer tv) {
        this.tv = tv;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
        return this.getChildren(inputElement);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getChildren(Object parentElement) {
        switch ((String) parentElement) {
            case "root":
                return new String[]{"1"};
            case "1":
                return new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
            default:
                return new String[0];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getParent(Object element) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasChildren(Object element) {
        return this.getChildren(element).length > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
    }

    @Override
    public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
    }
}
}
```

In this example, I only compare the node value with the string "b".

---

**Edit**: in this context, elements are immutable (for some reason they cannot be changed), and the solution with wrapping objects in tree nodes is not accepted (see comments).

In that case, you can save user check actions in a map, and when setting checked/unchecked state, search for any previous user check actions. I think it is reasonable to assume the map is simple and will not grow too much. User has to check a lot of nodes to get it big :)

I updated the snippet to keep track of user checks.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought about this solution already. The problem here is that you can't deselect this nodes then anymore. When a user expand the tree, the node is checked, which is fine so far. Now he want's to deselect it, which will work also. But when the user expand the tree for some reasons again (the tree hasn't closed), the node will checked again. A workarond here would be to additionally check if it's expand the first (using Boolean e.g.), but I'ld like to mind this solution.

Comment: @ph09 why not update the model whenever the user changes check-selection. Then, when the tree is expanded again, you will read the correct checked-unchecked value from the model. It will not work for my snippet, as I have immutable strings as values. If you cannot update the data model, you can always create a tree node class that stores the original value plus the checked-unchecked state.

Comment: I cannot update the model, as this is done by the underlying frameworks and I have not enough knowledge about this..
An additional tree node would be too complex and inefficient for large trees.

I'm wondering why there is no easy solution for this, especially because a method like setCheckedElements(Object[] elements) is offered to the user, which don't work initially.

Comment: @ph09 see my update in response to fix tracking of user check/uncheck actions.

Comment: Thx for your effort, but I think I found an easier solution..see update of my question. But thanky you anyway!!

Comment: @ph09 Indeed, that's much easier. But I will not remove my answer, in case somebody has huge trees where expanding all would take too much time (either because computing nodes is expensive or there number is huge and SWT tree in Windows is slow).